# Extract substring from string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have the following ddataframe:

```
                             Company Name        Time Expectation
0                Asta Funding Inc. (ASFI)  9:35 AM ET           -
1                       BlackBerry (BBRY)  7:00 AM ET     ($0.03)
2                    Carnival Corp. (CCL)  9:15 AM ET       $0.09
3                      Carnival PLC (CUK)  0:00 AM ET           -
```

I would like to have the company symbols in their own seperate column instead of inside the Company Name column. Right now I just have it iterate over the company names, and a RE pulls the symbols, puts it into a list, and then I apply it to the new column, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner/easier way.

I'm new to the whole map reduce lambda stuff.

```
for company in df['Company Name']:
    ticker = re.search("\(.*\)",company).group(0)
    ticker = ticker[1:len(ticker)-1]
    tickers.append(ticker)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Regex search is built into the Series class in pandas. You can find the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract).
In your case, you could use

```
df['ticker'] = df['Company Name'].str.extract("\((.*)\)")
```

Comment: I cannot get it to work still.  I'm using r"..." but it still is saying ValueError: This pattern contains no groups to capture.

Comment: @mobone Change the regex to `"\((.*)\)"`, note the added parantheses around `.*` to make this matched part a group

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/text.html) operates elementwise on a whole series. I assume that the company's symbol will always be at the end of the company name and surrounded by parantheses:

```
df['Company Symbol'] = df['Company Name'].str.rstrip(')').str.split('(').str[1] # Make new column
df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].str.replace(r'\(.*?\)$', '') # Remove symbol from company name
```