# Cleaning Data in a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data similar to the following in a pandas dataframe:

```
Address1 listboro:"Manhattan" listprice:1000000 listzip:"10001"
Address2 listprice:950000     listzip:"11205"   listboro:"Brooklyn"
```

I would like to create a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
Address   listboro   listprice listzip
Address1  Manhattan  1000000   10001
Address2  Brooklyn   950000    11205
```

There are two problems with the original dataframe:

1. data is inconsistently located (different items in different columns)
2. unnecessary strings precede each datapoint

I wanted to use the `startswith` method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970775/find-string-in-multiple-columns) and the `extraction` method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294017/extract-substring-from-string-in-dataframe), but the fact that the data is in inconsistent columns is throwing me off.

Comment: Can you please provide with actual `df.head()` of your dataframe with all columns if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to sort the values within each row of a pandas DataFrame without simply rebuilding a new DataFrame. Approach: sort each row in `numpy`, build these into a new DataFrame, and extract data fields with `Series.str.extract`:

```
# Example DataFrame
          0                     1                  2                    3
0  Address1  listboro:"Manhattan"  listprice:1000000      listzip:"10001"
1  Address2      listprice:950000    listzip:"11205"  listboro:"Brooklyn"

# Copy values to numpy array, sort each row, and re-build the DataFrame
a = df.values
a.sort(axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df
          0                     1                  2                3
0  Address1  listboro:"Manhattan"  listprice:1000000  listzip:"10001"
1  Address2   listboro:"Brooklyn"   listprice:950000  listzip:"11205"

# Assign names to columns
df.columns = ['Address', 'listboro', 'listprice', 'listzip']

# Extract data fields
df['listboro'] = df['listboro'].str.extract('\"(.*)\"')
df['listprice'] = df['listprice'].str.extract('\:(.*)').astype(int)
# Do not convert extracted ZIP codes from str to int, because 
# some ZIP codes start with 0
df['listzip'] = df['listzip'].str.extract('\"(.*)\"')

df
    Address   listboro          listprice listzip
0  Address1  Manhattan  listprice:1000000   10001
1  Address2   Brooklyn   listprice:950000   11205
```